# how to do substring in reverse mode in c#

Tags: c#, string, substring, reverse

My string is "csm15+abc-indiaurban@v2". I want only "indiaurban" from my string. what I am doing right now is :

```
var lastindexofplusminus = input.LastIndexOfAny(new char[]{'+','-'});

var lastindexofattherate = input.LastIndexOf('@');

string sub = input.Substring(lastindexofplusminus,lastindexofattherate);
```

but getting error "Index and length must refer to a location within the string."

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "Index and **length**" - you are passing two indexes.

Comment: then how to achieve only "indiaurban". Can you please give me the right substring.

Comment: Did you understand my comment? If so, you should be able to work it out yourself.

Answer (score 9):

You should put the `length` in the second argument (instead of passing another index) of the `Substring` you want to grab. Given that you know the two indexes, the translation to the length is pretty straight forward:

```
string sub = input.Substring(lastindexofplusminus + 1, lastindexofattherate - lastindexofplusminus - 1);
```

Note, `+1` is needed to get the char *after* your `lastindexofplusminus`.
`-1` is needed to get the `Substring` between them *minus* the `lastindexofattherate` itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple reverse the string, apply substring based on position and length, than reverse again.

```
string result = string.Join("", string.Join("", teste.Reverse()).Substring(1, 10).Reverse());
```

Or create a function:

```
public static string SubstringReverse(string str, int reverseIndex, int length) {
    return string.Join("", str.Reverse().Skip(reverseIndex - 1).Take(length));
}
```

[View function working here!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5PBI.png)

Comment: In the `SubstringReverse` function you are missing a `Reverse`. It should be `str.Reverse().Skip(reverseIndex - 1).Take(length).Reverse()`

Comment: Index's are usually [Zero-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). It would be less confusing if it is `Skip(reverseIndex)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
string input = "csm15+abc-indiaurban@v2";

string result = String.Join("", input.Reverse()
                                     .SkipWhile(c => c != '@')
                                     .Skip(1)
                                     .TakeWhile(c => c != '+' && c != '-')
                                     .Reverse());

Console.WriteLine(result); // indiaurban
```

Comment: I like the idea of `Reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is identify your break point but here is sample which is working

you can learn more about this at [String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
String s = "csm15+abc-indiaurban@v2";
        Char charRange = '-';
        Char charEnd = '@';
        int startIndex = s.IndexOf(charRange);
        int endIndex = s.LastIndexOf(charEnd);
        int length = endIndex - startIndex - 1;
        Label1.Text = s.Substring(startIndex+1, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 extension methods:

```
    public static string SubstrReverse(this string str, int reverseIndex, int length)
    {
        var startPos = str.Length -reverseIndex;
        return string.Join("", 
            str.Reverse()
            .Skip(startPos)
            .Take(length).Reverse());
    }

    public static string SubstrReverse(this string str, int reverseIndex)
    {
        var startPos = str.Length - reverseIndex;
        return string.Join("", 
            str.Reverse()
            .Skip(startPos)
            .Reverse());
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Assuming that your string is always in that format

```
string str = "csm15+abc-indiaurban@v2";
string subSTr = str.Substring(10).Substring(0,10);
```